# How to create fixed size Tkinter frame and place widgets within it using grid method

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a Tkinter app with fixed frame width. If a place widgets within a frame using pack() it works as expected. If i use grid(), it resizes to fit the widgets. I tried using the propagate method and it did not help. Below is my sample code. In frame1, the frame resizes. In frame2, the frame takes the given dimension. How can i create a frame with fixed width and use grid method place widgets within the frame

```
root = Tk()
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry(str(screen_width)+ 'x' +  str(screen_height))

frame1 = LabelFrame(root, text = 'Frame1', width= 400, height = 400)
frame1.pack()
frame1.propagate(0)

label1 = Label(frame1, text = 'Label1')
label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

label2 = Label(frame1, text = 'Label2')
label2.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

frame2 = LabelFrame(root, text = 'Search', width= 400, height = 400)
frame2.pack()
frame2.propagate(0)

label3 = Label(frame2, text = 'Label3')
label3.pack()
label4 = Label(frame2, text = 'Label4')
label4.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Use `frame1.grid_propagate(0)` instead since you use `grid()`. `propagate()` is the same as `pack_propagate()`.

Comment: Not sure i understood your suggestion @acw1668, tried using frame1.grid_propagate(0) it did not work as expected.

Comment: and what do you expect? When I use `frame1.grid_propagate(0)` then `frame1` has the same size (`width` and `height`) as `frame2`. I tested on Linux but I think it should work the same on WIndows.